# How to run Python script with VBA on a Mac?

Tags: python, excel, vba, macos

I am trying to run a VBA script, on a Mac, that runs a Python script in the same folder.

```vb
Dim argh2 As Double
argh2 = Shell("python3 " & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\audit_files.py ")
```

I expect the terminal to pop up and the file to run.

I get error 76.

Any solutions I can use with built-in Excel VBA? I have seen solutions with imported items.

Update: I have also tried the following. This also gives the 76 error.

```vb
argh3 = Shell(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/run_python.sh")
```

Comment: path structures are different on macs. Have you verified it generates a valid path?

Comment: @QHarr how would I do that? Not too advanced in VBA sadly

Comment: Most likely you need a forward slash rather than a backslash.

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman, neither slash type works here

Comment: So after research it seems the Mac Sandboxing makes this a very onerous process. I am abandoing this effort to try a better method to run python scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after research it seems the Mac Sandboxing makes this a very onerous process. I am abandoing this effort to try a better method to run python scripts.

Answer (score 0):

on excel client i have a combo box with two values: if value ="WIN" i use code that works, in case of "MAC" i create a msgbox that tells to pen visul studio for direct excecuting *.py file